# How one interface can be used for more than two background android tasks within one activity?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an activity class which is calling background AsyncTask twice like

```
BackgroundTask bt1 = new BackgroundTask(this, ApiHelper.GET);
bt.execute(url1);

BackgroundTask bt2 = new BackgroundTask(this, ApiHelper.POST, params);
bt.execute(url2);
```

one is used to GET the data and another is used to POST the data to server.

Constructors of this AsyncTask is as follows

```
public BackgroundTask(Context context, String method) {
    this.context = context;
    this.method = method;
    this.callback = (onBackgroundTaskListener<String>) context;
}

public BackgroundTask(Context context, String method, ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {
    this.context = context;
    this.method = method;
    this.callback = (onBackgroundTaskListener<String>) context;
    this.params = params;
}
```

Now MainActivity.class is implemented by `onBackgroundTaskListener<String>` interface as

```
public interface onBackgroundTaskListener<T> {
    void onTaskComplete(T result);
}
```

onPostExecute of AsyncTask class, `String result` is returned or passed back to the calling class, shown below.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    callback.onTaskComplete(result);
}
```

Now I have one method (onTaskComplete) in MainActivity to tackle two responses coming from one background task. I would like to use the condition to figure out which execution is returned a result like...

```
@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String result) {
    if (execution == 1) { 
        // Parse the GET result
    } else if(execution == 2) { 
        // Parse the POST result
    }
}
```

I don't want to implement the multiple AsyncTask and would like to achieve it using single AsyncTask and called this AsyncTask multiple times within single activity. What should be the possible way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum BackgroundType{ GET, POST }

public interface onBackgroundTaskListener<T> {
    void onTaskComplete(T result, BackgroundType type);
}

--------------------------
BackgroundTask bt1 = new BackgroundTask(this, ApiHelper.GET, GET);
bt.execute(url1);

BackgroundTask bt2 = new BackgroundTask(this, ApiHelper.POST, params, POST);
bt.execute(url2);
------------------------
@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String result,  BackgroundType type) {
    switch(type){
      case GET:
         break;
      case POST:
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a new class and use this class instead of `String` when creating `AsyncTask` and communicating result back from the `AsyncTask`

Then the new class can then encapsulate the string you require along with other variables you would need.

For example:

```
// Create a new class to hold the result of `AsyncTask` execution
public class TaskExecutionResult {
    public String method;
    public String resultString;
}

// When subclassing AsyncType assign TaskExecutionResult as return type
// Please replace URL with input parameters you require (perhaps a method string)
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, TaskExecutionResult> {

    // doInBackground will now return TaskExecutionResult type of object
    protected TaskExecutionResult doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // Here populate a value which will identify your AsyncTask into return value (perhaps a method string)
        ...
    }

    // onPostExecute will also accept TaskExecutionResult type of object
    protected void onPostExecute(TaskExecutionResult result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        callback.onTaskComplete(result);
    }
}
```

Then use TaskExecutionResult in onTaskComplete:

```
public void onTaskComplete(TaskExecutionResult result) {
    if (result.method.equals("GET")) { 
        // Parse the GET result (from result.resultString)
    } else if(result.method.equals("POST")) { 
        // Parse the POST result (from result.resultString)
    }
}
```

This approach will also allow you to easily update the result object if you needed to add more return variables.

Comment: could you please elaborate more. Could not understand what you want say.

Comment: @rpurant, I've added an example. Hope it helps